# How to programmatically generate ID for table using stored procedure and insert?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I have created a `Student` table in my database, and I need to use a stored procedure to generate unique `StudentID` when inserting new rows, which should start at 005 up to and including 025.

```
create procedure FillStudent
as
    insert into Student(StudentID)
    values (005)
go
```

But then I am thinking, what if it becomes 2 digits? Would it automatically do 010? Or would it be 0010? If it would be the last one, What's the best approach to make it so like '010'? I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Typically these sorts of questions relate back to the most recent topics covered in your course. So - what are they? Did you discuss identity columns? Sequences? Something else. In addition, the goal - as defined - is suspiciously stated. One generally does not put an upper bound on an ID column since that will limit the number of rows that can exist in the table (assuming that column has uniqueness enforced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with this code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[StudentsID] 
START WITH 5
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 25;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
    [StudentID] CHAR(3)
);


GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FillStudent]
AS
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] ([StudentID])
    VALUES (RIGHT(NEXT VALUE FOR  [dbo].[StudentsID] + 1000, 3));
END;
GO

GO

EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];
EXEC [dbo].[FillStudent];

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Student];



DROP TABLE [dbo].[Student];
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[FillStudent];
DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[StudentsID];
```

[image]

The idea is to use [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) object.

If you need to use identity column you can create the table with identity column, computed column (this is the value you need) and a check constraint to stop adding records after id = 25 is reach. Execute the script below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
     [ID] TINYINT IDENTITY(5, 1)
    ,[StudentID] AS RIGHT([ID] + 1000, 3) PERSISTED
    ,CONSTRAINT CK_Student CHECK  ([ID] < 26)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] DEFAULT VALUES;


SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Student]

DROP TABLE [dbo].[Student];
```

You can see after the record with `ID = 25` you are getting an error.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been playing with this code and it works perfectly fine. But we haven't come across 'sequence' topic.

Comment: @denise is it helpful? let me know if you have any questions/issues

Comment: in my case, i need another way to approach the problem. tho i tried to run the code you provided, it was working fine. I am thinking of declaring a variable then do 'while loop' then do an 'insert'?? do you think that will be a good idea?

Comment: @denise You can do it in loop, too - it will be easier, but what's the final goal? You can add `identity` column to your table and then to add a compute column which is calculating the `XXX` value, also.

Comment: the goal is to fill the Student table with 005-025 StudentID using insert and I should use a single multi-element `insert` to add the `StudentID`. I can sure use `@@IDENTITY` and do a `while loop` while it is less than 26?? Also, another goal is to make the `StudentID` format like 005, 010 and not just plain 5,6,7,10.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `StudentID` column an identity column. In your case set the seed value as 5 and increment as 1.

`[StudentID] [int] IDENTITY(5,1) NOT NULL`

Then SQL Server will automatically populate that column for you. Just ignore that column in your `INSERT` statement.

Never try to add leading zeros into the actual data stored in the table. That is not a good approach. Recommended way is to achieve such requirements via formatting the data upon retrieval. You can achieve it as follows.

`REPLACE(STR([StudentID],3),' ','0')`